# `gcc -print-file-name=libc.a` prints absolute path in the strange form

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I run this command:

```
gcc -print-file-name=libc.a
```

and get the absolute name of the requested file (C standard library):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

if I change directory to this path and run the `pwd` command, I get

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The question is: why the absolute path have printed in such strange form, using `/../../../` (first, go to three directories down, then go back to the parent directory three times), why it doesn’t printed simply `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, an actual path to the file? Does it have a reason for printing such way?

Comment: Wow, thats weird, I come to check it too. The only way I can think this is usefull is that it first check that the directory `5/` under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/` does exist, but then it comes back and only will use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu as path`. Just an hypothesis.

Comment: Presumably, the form in which the filename is presented reflects the way certain path strings are recorded inside the gcc binary.  I can imagine reasons why they might be stored that way, but ultimately, the reason is immaterial.  The particular form has no special significance that should matter to you.

Comment: Things are different if there are symlinks involved.

Comment: @melpomene I know about symlinks, but it's not the case. Or I have missed something?